# How to compute max from array?

Tags: r

This an array:

```
 a <- array(1:16, c(2, 2, 2))
```

my desir output is this:

```
                [,1] [,2]
          [1,]    5    7
          [2,]    6    8
```

I tried these but not what I wanted:

```
      apply(a,2,max)
      max(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

We need to specify the `MARGIN` correctly to apply the `max` on the coresponding elements

```
apply(a, c(1, 2), max)
#.     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    5    7
#[2,]    6    8
```

---

If we are using `matrixStats`, then with `rowMaxs`, the same `MARGIN` from OP's post should work

```
library(matrixStats)
apply(a, 2, rowMaxs)
```